# Express-validator - Validation not showing error messages

Tags: node.js, express-validator

I have very basic idea about nodejs and i am learning it.
I am testing login module and based on some existing questions and documentations.

I have come up with these codes.

**Router.js**

```
router.post("/login", validateUserSignIn, loginValidationErrors, login);
```

**Validator.js**

```
exports.validateUserSignIn = [

    oneOf([
        check('email').trim().isEmail().withMessage('email or mobile no is required!'),//.custom((value) => {console.log(value);}) ,
        check('mobile').trim().isLength({min:10,max:12}).withMessage('Mobile no must be 10-12 digit long'),// .custom((value) => {console.log(value);}),
        ]),
    check('password')
      .trim()
      .not()
      .isEmpty()
      .withMessage('email / password is required!'),
  ];

exports.loginValidationErrors = (req, res, next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    //console.log(errors);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }
  
    next();
  };
```

When i run the API in postman i am not getting messages defined in validateUserSignIn.
I am expecting **email or mobile no is required!** or **Mobile no must be 10-12 digit long**

However, I am getting **Invalid value(s)**.

No idea what is happening and how to fix it.

**Edit**

This is the output in postman.

```
{"errors":[{"type":"alternative_grouped","msg":"Invalid value(s)","nestedErrors":[[{"type":"field","value":"123testgmail.com","msg":"email or mobile no is required!","path":"email","location":"body"}],[{"type":"field","value":"7110245","msg":"Mobile no must be 10-12 digit long","path":"mobile","location":"body"}]]}]}
```